# How to check type of Swift object, produced by factory method?

Tags: swift, factory

I have an [array of TemplateASTNode objects](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache.swift/blob/master/Sources/TemplateASTNode.swift#L26):

```swift
enum TemplateASTNode {
    case blockNode(Block)
    case sectionNode(Section)
    case textNode(String)
    
    
    // Define structs instead of long tuples
    struct Block {
        let innerTemplateAST: TemplateAST
        let name: String
    }
    
    struct Section {
        let tag: SectionTag
        let expression: Expression
        let inverted: Bool
    }
    
    // Factory methods
    static func block(innerTemplateAST: TemplateAST, name: String) -> TemplateASTNode {
        return .blockNode(Block(innerTemplateAST: innerTemplateAST, name: name))
    }
    
    static func section(templateAST: TemplateAST, expression: Expression, inverted: Bool, openingToken: TemplateToken, innerTemplateString: String) -> TemplateASTNode {
        let tag = SectionTag(innerTemplateAST: templateAST, openingToken: openingToken, innerTemplateString: innerTemplateString)
        return .sectionNode(Section(tag: tag, expression: expression, inverted: inverted))
    }
    
    static func text(text: String) -> TemplateASTNode {
        return .textNode(text)
    }
}
```

Objects are constructed with different factory methods — `section`, `text`, `block`, but in debugger actual class is `TemplateASTNode`.

1. **How to check actual type of `TemplateASTNode` instance — Section, Text, Block?**
2. **How exacly this mechanism works? Need a start point what to google.**

Swift magic seems a bit confusing for me:

1. we call factory method `section()`
2. it calls case `sectionNode` — I suppose it's a pointer to Enum attribute/choice
3. sectionNode holds a pointer to constructor Section which is a private structure inside TemplateASTNode

I expect a struct of type Section should be instantiated, but the generic TemplateASTNode one is produced. Why?

Comment: The usual way to distinguish the cases of an enum (with associated values) is a `switch` statement.

Comment: @vadian oh, great, case checking works! But could you explain why we call an internal struct factory method, but getting a Enum instance in the end?

Comment: It's not mutually exclusive. In the factory method you create and return an instance.

Comment: As they say, RTFM: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why TemplateASTNode is Created

So the functions are actually using a `case` of the enum, this `case` could be `.textNode` but that case requires a string, which you give it.

So essentially the TemplateASTNode is acting as a wrapper to centralise all these models into one place, and your actual Structs are being held **within** the enum `cases`

Therefor you get given back a TemplateASTNode, which in this case could either be a `.textNode` `.blockNode` or `.sectionNode` each containing their respective data.

#### How to distinguish between them

As we've just established, these are all `cases` therefore we can use something called a `switch`. To sum up what this does, it essentially allows you to give it an enum, then add logic depending on which `case` it is. So for you, you'd want something like this:

```swift
switch templateASTNode { // These should be the variable and not the class
    case .textNode(let text):
        // Perform logic for text node

    case .sectionNode(let section):
        // Perform logic for section node

    case .blockNode(let block):
        // Perform logic for block node
}
```